# How to create a band.conf File for Phonon Calculations of Graphene with DFPT Method?

Tags: vasp, phonopy, phonon-dispersion, dfpt

How can one generate a band.conf file for performing phonon calculations of graphene with a
dim 1x1x1 using the (DFPT) method?